# Rotating an embedded matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

I've created a fairly simple `matplotlib` plot using `Basemap` and then I have embedded it into a `tkinter` frame using the outline in the matplotlib documentations and referencing the questions posted here as well.  I've looked at the other questions I've found about embedding a `matplotlib`plot into a `tkinter` frame and still cannot find a solution to this problem. Alternatively, I've tried different ways of creating the canvas / frame as I suspect that is where the real problem lies by moving the frame creation outside of the class and other approaches. As when I use the below method and I include say a tkinter button that uses `exit()` or `destroy()` to close the window I get a maximum recursion depth error.

However, I still cannot rotate the embedded plot for some reason, and even weirder if I uncomment the line below that I've annotated in the code block I can rotate the plot. This doesn't make sense to me as it seems entirely redundant it just creates another blank window and then I'm allowed to rotate the plot again for some reason I don't understand.

As another attempted  soltuion I tried using `Axes3D.init_mouse` as I've seen that posted as an answer to a similar question, but this did not work either.

Here are the relevant code blocks

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.fig = None
        self.map = None
        self.axes = None
        self.polygon_border = "black"


    def init_plot(self):

        self.fig = plot.figure()
        self.map = Basemap()
        self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)
        self.axes.azim = 270
        self.axes.elev = 50
        self.axes.dist = 10
        self.axes.add_collection3d(self.map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 0.25))
        self.axes.add_collection3d(self.map.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.35))
        self.axes.add_collection3d(self.map.drawstates(linewidth = 0.1))

        self.create_polygons()
        self.fig = self.axes.get_figure()

        #uncommenting the below line allows for rotation inside of tkitner albeit very slowly and somewhat crudely
        #plot.show()

   def init_frame(self):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master = self.frame)
        self.canvas.show()
        #Axes3D.mouse_init(self.fig)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar.pack()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, 
                                    expand = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following was my eventual solution, in a simplified form. I had problems with my structure some of which were `self.canvas` which needed to be created before the 3D axes could be added to the canvas, otherwise it resulted in the `Axes3D.mouse_init` error where it wouldn't allow rotation as it couldn't find a canvas. I'm assuming that this is why the redundant line that's commented out was allowing rotation when uncommented.

Also, you need to use `plot` from `pyplot` and not `figure` otherwise the polygons from `Basemap` will show incorrectly.

Not 100% sure if all of the above is accurate, but this is what I've found after playing around and testing.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D #For plotting 3D Axes
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap #For plotting polygonal surfaces
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection #Polygons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib, sys     
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backnds.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,\
    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
f = plot.figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master = root)
axes = Axes3D(f)

map = Basemap()

axes.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 0.3, color = "white"))
axes.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.3, color = "white"))
axes.add_collection3d(map.drawstates(linewidth = 0.3, color = "white"))


polygons = []
for polygon in map.landpolygons:
    polygons.append(polygon.get_coords())
    collection = PolyCollection(polygons, edgecolor = "white",
                               facecolor = "black", 
                            closed = True)

axes.add_collection3d(collection)


canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)
button = tk.Button(master = root, text = "Exit", command = sys.exit)
button.pack(side = tk.TOP)

tk.mainloop()
```